# Odoo 11 : ImportError No Module Named 'PyPDF2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04, odoo-11

I'm using a script to run Odoo11 via PyCharm in Ubuntu (`openerp_openserver` script)

[image: script]

When I try to run the program, it fails at some point, when it import pdf module and I have this error:

> `ImportError No Module Named 'PyPDF2'`

as you can see in this image:

[image]

I Already installed PyPDF2 via this command (i have python3.5 already installed) :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pypdf2
```

[image]

So I'm wondering, what is the problem, why PyCharm cannot find and import pypdf2?

**EDIT:**

When I Try to import PyPDF2 using the Python command, I don't have error

[image]

Comment: Can you try to import this library from python console please?

Comment: yes it works when i use the python console : python3. import PyPDF2 works perfect

Comment: Okay. We figured out that the problem is in PyCharm. Can you find the interpreter path that PyCharm is using? 
In PyCharm `Ctrl-Alt-S > Build, Execution Deployment > Console > Python Console > Python Console` and check the path to python interpreter. It should be `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Thanks !! exactly that was the problem . the path python Interpreter was pointing to Odoo11/ven/bin/python instead of /usr/bin/python3.5 , you saved my day !

Comment: Glad I helped you. May I submit an answer to your question here?

Comment: sure ! you can !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should try to check whether you can import PyPDF2 library from a Python console.

Run from your native console:

```
python3 -c "import PyPDF2"
```

If no error message occurs, the problem is not in the library.

Check a path of python interpreter that is used by PyCharm.

Navigate inside PyCharm:

```
Ctrl-Alt-S > Build, Execution Deployment > Console > Python Console
```

The path should be to `/usr/bin/`folder.

If not - change it to a path of the desirable python interpreter that is inside `/usr/bin/` folder.

Will be good if someone can add a way to solve this type of problem in Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you may try installing psycopg2 and requirements again for venv(virtualenvironment.
For psycopg2 install you should follow the steps under "**Virtual Environment Installation Notes**" title on http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/